# java jdbc type 1 driver: thread safe or not?

Tags: java, jdbc

Are methods in JDBC thread safe?

Comment: I just want to understand since I am curious. I am not arguing with it or anything: why is this so downvoted? Is the question somehow not valid, a repeat, not properly asked, not enough info, etc? (I myself know nothing about jdbc, in fact I've never even heard of it)

Comment: @AshwinGupta The question was originally 95% fluff until I fixed it.

Comment: @EJP oh got you, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes,It is thread safe because of synchronized method in the jdbc type 1 driver.

Answer (score 1):

The [type 1 driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver#Type_1_driver_.E2.80.93_JDBC-ODBC_bridge) (or the JDBC-ODBC bridge) uses native code, and **no** the database access is not thread safe.

Comment: Would u please elaborate. i can't understand soo

Comment: @lohithkumar What part of 'no' or 'not thread safe' don't you understand?

Comment: i'm asking that, is the methods in jdbc driver are synchronized methods are not?

Comment: @lohithkumar It follows from the fact that it isn't thread-safe that they aren't synchronized, or at least not sufficiently synchronized to be thread-safe. It's the thread-safety you should be worrying about, not the synchronization.